# Change google assistance voice

Tags: javascript, node.js, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I am using Google's dialogflow Essentials. I need to change the display name and Google assistant voice based on condition. For now I am changing the both from the console but I need to do it from node code which is programmatically. Is there is any way to do it ? I have connected my dialogflow with the webhook. I have given that code below.

**Code**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const df = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');

app.post('/', express.json(), (req, res) => {
    const agent = new df.WebhookClient({
        request: req,
        response: res
    });

    function getTime(agent) {
        var breakfastTime = agent.context.get('breakfast_time');
       agent.add("Thank you, Have a great day")

        }
    }

    var intentMap = new Map();
    intentMap.set('breakfast', getTime);
    agent.handleRequest(intentMap);

})
```

**Manual Name and Voice Change from Console Screen**

[image: Console]

Comment: To be clear, are you writing an Action for the Google Assistant? Which version of Dialogflow are you using (you've tagged it for both ES and CX)?

Comment: Sorry. I will remove now. Its for ES

Comment: Just want to make sure its clear. And this is specifically for an Action that works with the Google Assistant? You've also indicated a change in the display name, can you provide an example of what you'd like it to do?

Comment: I have 4 characters in front end. Each has a different name and voice  . If user clicks one character the google assistant display name should be a custom name which I set and select to voice Male 1. If they select next character. It has different custom name and select to voice Male 2.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "front end" if you're talking about the Google Assistant. Can you update your question to illustrate what you're trying to do?